# Variable inside of asset declaration

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am trying to randomise a background using Laravel. I pass the $background variable to the view and then try to load it as an inline style.

However, I am struggling to declare the path to the asset and then call the variable together as it keeps erroring out.

My current code is :

```
<section class="page" style="background-image: url({{ asset('img/backgrounds/{{ $background }}.jpg') }});">
```

The $background is the variable and I am trying to reference the asset path.

Is there a better / easier way to do this? Or how can I get this to work. Don't mind using PHP code as an alternative if needs be.

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't nest Blade tags, so you can't have `{{.. {{...}} ..}}`, but you don't need to, because the code inside a `{{...}}` is evaluated as if it were a `<?php echo ... ?>` snippet. So you can do one of two things:

Concatenate the variable into the string:

```
{{ asset('img/backgrounds/' . $background . '.jpg') }}
```

Or use *double quotes* `"` to evaluate the variable inside the string:

```
{{ asset("img/backgrounds/$background.jpg") }}
```

Comment: Tha's great. Thank you! Great explanation too!

Comment: first solution works for me (laravel 7), second one not, with array : "img/background/$myArray['myAttribute']"

Comment: @bcag2 You actually can reference an associative array key inside a double quoted string. Just surround the variable with curly braces like so `asset("img/background/{$myArray['myAttribute']}")`.